# How to increase the row height in a Vaadin 11.0.0 grid?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I want to implement word-wrap in a grid in Vaadin 11. As far as I understand, you need to do two things for this:

1. Set the style of the respective cell.
2. Increase the row height.

I did the first step using the following code:

productsGrid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.of(
                "[[item.name]]")
                .withProperty("name", Product::getName))
                .setHeader("Name");

Now I need to increase the row height.

Maybe it's possible to do it using `productsGrid.getElement().getStyle().set(...)`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

How can I increase the height of rows in a Vaadin 11 grid (i. e. make the rows taller so that I can display long texts in the cells)?

**Update 1:**

I'm using the following code to create the grid:

```
private Grid<Product> createProductsGrid() {
    final Grid<Product> productsGrid = new Grid<Product>();
    productsGrid.setItems(Arrays.asList(AltFondUtilities.INSTANCE));
    productsGrid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Product>of(
                    "<div style='word-wrap: break-word;'>[[item.name]]</div>")
                    .withProperty("name", Product::getName))
                    .setHeader("Название");
    productsGrid.addColumn(Product::getInterestRatePercentPerAnnum)
                    .setHeader("Ставка");
    productsGrid.addColumn(Product::getProvider).setHeader("Организация");
    productsGrid.setHeightByRows(true);
    return productsGrid;
}
```

Result: The word wrap doesn't work even though the `name` column has the right style.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To make the cells wrap, add the theme for it:  `grid.element.themeList.addAll('wrap-cell-content')`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Examples of Grid](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/height-by-rows) from Vaadin 11 it appears that this is possible with the use of `setHeightByRows`

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();

// When using heightByRows, all items are fetched and
// Grid uses all the space needed to render everything.
grid.setHeightByRows(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I posted the code that I use to create the grid in update 1 to the question, as well as a screenshot of what I get.

Comment: setHeightByRows is about the size of the grid altogether, not a single row. This question is about sizes of single rows

Answer (score 0):

Setting of row height is depend upon the theme which is used. If the UI is using the LUMO theme then the row height of table can be changed with below hack.

```
        Grid<Object> grid = new Grid<>();        
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-line-height-xs", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-line-height-s", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-size-xs", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-size-s", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-space-xs", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("--lumo-space-s", "0");
        grid.getStyle().set("margin-top", "20px");
        grid.getStyle().set("line-height", "20px");
```